# Replicating a site without access to any files or knowledge of cms used

Tags: html, css, flash, copy, duplicates

I am in a unique position where my client is at a disagreement with the company that built her site and is hosting it then the company took down the site. She needs me to replicate her site as is. I was able to find her site on the following link which is not the domain that was taken down but still shows the site. Is there anyway to replicate this? I tried HTTrack and saving the pages from the browser but both did not replicate everything.

http://roederickmontemayor.com/sites/jyankauskas/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might come across a similar problem, I used HTTrack to copy all files on a folder on my desktop. The flash banner did not copy so I right clicked on the page in firefox and chose "view page info" then clicked on media and selected the embed for the flash banner then saved as. In netbeans I created a new project and copied and pasted all the files into the root folder, then moved the swf file into the flash folder and I had an exact replicate of the site and a very happy client who got to keep her site. There might be easier ways to do it but this was what I did.